# How to mod2^64 in long in Java?

Tags: java, modulo

I'm implementing a Skein hash function in Java, and I have a problem with a part where some additions where modulo 2^64. As I we know, long in java has max value = 2^63-1. So my problem is, how to implement this modulo operation.
(All operations in Skein are on 64bit words.)

Comment: If you do not need it to be super fast, you can use [`BigInteger`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`long` in Java is 64-bit so all operations are mod 2^64 already. You don't have to do anything extra to make that happen.

Is the problem that you don't know how to handle signed values?

Is this something you want or is it something you are trying to avoid?

Comment: Thank you, this was helpful. This is exactly what i want. I will be operating only on bits at the end, so I don't care about a bit of sign.

Comment: The only problem you have is for operations where the sign matters. e.g. Long.toString(long) will print a sign.  However, many operations work on the bits as you would expect unsigned or signed.

Comment: At the end of all operations, I will be assembling all 64bit words into Byte[] of 512 bits, and then I will be interpreting all as hex or string, I don't know yet.

Comment: So you have 8 64-bit longs.  You can write them to a ByteBuffer and read them as bytes. or wrap a `byte[]` (not a Byte[]

Answer (score 3):

[`BigInteger`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) is one way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Peter's answer, I want to suggest taking a look at the great [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) library. It has a class [UnsignedLongs](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/primitives/UnsignedLongs.html) which offers several utility functions for working with longs treating them as unsigned. This might be helpful for you.

Comment: Author of `UnsignedLongs` here: Peter's answer is mostly accurate even for unsigned longs.  Specifically, +, -, and * are all correct even if you treat long values as unsigned.

Additionally, you may find it helpful to just use the `UnsignedLong` wrapper class, which you can use like `BigInteger` but works mod 2^64.